# How can I make this function run quicker?

Tags: matlab, matrix, solver

I have written this code that solves a banded matrix using jacobi iteration. It's a modified Jacobi function that is "optimized" to work quicker on banded matrices. I have successfully modified it only compute non zero terms in the matrix, but it runs much slower than the original code. How can I make it run more efficiently?

Original code:

```
while (true)
iter = iter+1;
for r=1:m                           % looping through all rows of A
    sum = 0;                        % setting sum equal to 0
    for c=1:n                       % looping through all columns of A
        if r~=c                     % if the r does not equal c, meaning the current elements are not diagonals...
            sum = sum + A(r,c)*x0(c);% set sum = sum plus current element times cth element of x
        end

    x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,r);    % if r and c are diagonals, the x value at that element is -sum + b(r) divided by that element of A

    end
end
if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL    % checking tolerance
    break
end
x0 = x;                             % setting x0 = x before relooping
end
```

Banded Code:

```
while (true)
%     iter = iter+1; 
for r=1:m                           % looping through all rows of A  
  for i = 1:hi                      % looping through the section of A at the beginning that does not have a complete "low"
      sum = 0;                      % assigning sum = 0 for each loop
    for r = i                       % looping through rows of first section
       for c = 1:r+hi;              % looping through only columns that go from the first column to hi after the diagona
        if r~=c                     % if the r does not equal c, meaning the current elements are not diagonals...
            sum = sum + A(r,c)*x0(c);% set sum = sum plus current element times cth element of x
          end
    x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,r);    % solving the row
       end

    end
  end
  for i = 1+hi:n-hi                 % looping through second section (section with a complete "low" and "hi" for each diagonal
      sum = 0;                      % setting sum = 0 for each loop
    for r = i                       % looping through each row of second section
       for c = r+low:r+hi;          % looping through only columns of current row that are in the bandwidth
        if r~=c                     % if the r does not equal c, meaning the current elements are not diagonals...
            sum = sum + A(r,c)*x0(c);% set sum = sum plus current element times cth element of x
        end

    x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,r);     % solving current row
       end

      end
  end
  for i = n+low+1:n                 % looping through final section of A (section with out a complete "hi" for each diagonal
      sum = 0;                      % setting sum = 0 for each loop
    for r = i                       % looping through each row of final section
       for c = r + low:n;           % looping through only columns of current row that are from "low" away from the diagonal to the end of the row
        if r~=c                     % if the r does not equal c, meaning the current elements are not diagonals...
            sum = sum + A(r,c)*x0(c);% set sum = sum plus current element times cth element of x
        end   
    x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,r);    % solving current row
       end   
    end
  end
end
if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL    % checking tolerance
    break
end 
   x0 = x;                              % assigning x0 as the new estimate from the previous attempt, x
end
sln = x0;                               % assigning output variable
```

The changes I made to it were dividing it up into 3 sections (1 for the section of a band that doesn't have a complete "low" and "hi" at the start, 1 for the same at the end, and 1 for the section in the middle. Then I changed the loop to start at low and go to hi. why is this function taking so long to run? It takes about a minute for a 20x20 matrix.

Comment: did you put in in a function or are you running it as a script? Put it in a function and run it multiple times, so that JIT would kick in....

Comment: Great. Did you profile the code?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Do `profile on` first and run your function, then do `profile viewer`. It shows how much time each line of your code took. Beware that running the profiler takes longer.

Comment: It spends the most time in that second section, which is to be expected